# How to dynamically create a pivot table on MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot

I'm having difficulties creating the result i want on a specific situation.

I have a two tables:

1: sales by warehouse:

+-------------+---------------+--------------+

warehouse     |     type    --------  |      value

+-------------+---------------+--------------+

A--------------XX-------------234234----------

A--------------                    YY------------               234343--------------

A--------------                    ZZ------------               534534--------------

B--------------                    XX------------               234432--------------

B--------------                    YY------------               767563--------------

B--------------                    ZZ------------               312332--------------

c--------------                    XX------------               234234--------------

....

2: users by warehouse:

user--------|---warehouse

john--------|--            A

john--------|--           B

john--------|--           C

peter-------|--           A

Daniel------|--          C

Kim---------|--           B

Kim---------|--           C

....

So i created this query:

select a.warehouse, type, value from sales_by_warehouse A
left join users_warehouse B
ON A.warehouse=B.warehouse
where b.user = 'user_logged_on_software'

This works perfectly by giving me the warehouse that the user has access to and its values but, now, i wanted to invert the result such as in a pivot table so that if the user was Peter, this would be the result:

type--|-----A----

XX----|-----123123

YY----|-----3423423

ZZ----|-----3423345

And if the user was kim:

type--|-----B---------|-----C

XX----|-----123123-|---234324

YY----|-----423423-|---245435

ZZ----|-----423345-|---456233

Is there a way to do this with only select statements, without views or PS?

Comment: Read [this](http://tkyte.blogspot.de/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: AFAIK, not dynamically in MySQL.

Comment: What if `(B, XX)` is not unique? Should you have 2 rows or 2 columns?